# Javascript: Split and tokenize provided string

Tags: javascript, regex, string

Here’s a javascript requirement that I’m dealing with:
given such a string:

```
“  [   condition12  (BRAND) IN 'Beats by Dr. Dre & D\’Silva of type Band’   of type  'IDENTIFIER_STRING’ ]   ”
```

I want to tokenize and extract:

```
- condition12
- BRAND
- IN
- Beats by Dr. Dre & D\’Silva of type Band
- IDENTIFIER_STRING
```

Here’s an algorithm I was considering to perform:

- remove the first & last square braces: .trim().slice(1, -1)
- delete the last occurrence of ‘of type’
- split the string using space (ignoring multiple occurrences): .split(/\s+/g))
- removed the first & last single quote from the last array element (that’ll contain ‘IDENTIFIER_STRING’ or similar)
- from the main string, create substring between firstIndexOf(“’”) and lastIndexOf(‘of type’) & trim it to get ’Beats by Dr. Dre & D\’Silva of type Band’

Now the question to all you experts, is there a cleaner way to approach this :)?

Thanks in advance!

~VS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all you want with one regex:

```
str = "  [   condition12  (BRAND) IN 'Beats by Dr. Dre & D\'Silva of type Band'   of type  'IDENTIFIER_STRING' ]   ";
matches = str.match(/^\s*\[\s*(.*?)\s+\((.*?)\)\s+(.*?)\s+'(.*?)'\s+.*?'(.*?)'\s*\]\s*$/);
```

Result:

```
matches[1]: "condition12"
matches[2]: "BRAND"
matches[3]: "IN"
matches[4]: "Beats by Dr. Dre & D'Silva of type Band"
matches[5]: "IDENTIFIER_STRING"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use one regex!  The values you are interested in will be in matches[1] through matches[5].

You might need to tweak this regex depending on which characters are present in the various tokens.  (eg, it assumes there is some whitespace then the condition then more whitespace, it will break if there is whitespace IN the condition).  You can work out the regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/NBEb2A/1)

```js
var str = "[   condition12  (BRAND) IN 'Beats by Dr. Dre & D\'Silva of type Band'   of type  'IDENTIFIER_STRING' ]";
var re = /\[\s+(\S+)\s+\((.*)\)\s+(\S+)\s+'(.*)'\s+of type\s+'(.*)'\s+\]/;

var matches = re.exec(str);

console.log(matches);
```

Comment: Thanks so much! For some reason when I execute this, it does not print "IN".

Comment: Oh I missed that one.  Try now.